# How to pass a register of qubits through an Oracle object in Q#

Tags: quantum-computing, q#

Suppose I made a ReflectionOracle object using ReflectionStart() function which reflects about the |00...00> axis. But how do I pass my register of qubits through this oracle? Since this Oracle is an object I can't use it as a function. Is there a standard library tool similar to UseOracle(reflectionoracle,register) ?

Comment: FYI: There is a dedicated https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Functions are first class objects in Q#, so you can just invoke on the variable where you store the result of calling `ReflectionStart`. More over, because it is an operation that has `adjoint`, you can also invoke adjoint on it, for example:

```
operation Operation () : ()
{
    body
    {
        using (qubits = Qubit[5])
        {
            let oracle = ReflectionStart();
            oracle(0.5, qubits);
            (Adjoint oracle)(0.5, qubits);
        }
    }
}
```